# How to print OpenTK (OpenGL) or change device context?

Tags: printing, opentk

With OpenTK / OpenGL I can draw onto the Winforms all fine.
But how do I draw on to the printer?

I worked on a [ganttchart](http://ganttchart.codeplex.com/) and used this piece of code for printing but I am not sure how to get the device context to get into GLControl.

```
private void print_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dialog.Document = new PrintDocument();
    using (var dialog = new PrintDialog())
    {
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            dialog.Document.BeginPrint += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventHandler(Document_BeginPrint);
            dialog.Document.EndPrint += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventHandler(Document_EndPrint);
            dialog.Document.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(Document_PrintPage);
            dialog.Document.Print();
        }
    }
}

void Document_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    // This code does not work!
    // something to do with e.Graphics.GetHdc() ???
    var nullWindow = OpenTK.Platform.Utilities.CreateWindowsWindowInfo(IntPtr.Zero);
    // Exception of type 'OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsContextException' was thrown.
    var printcontext = new OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsContext(new ContextHandle(e.Graphics.GetHdc()), nullWindow);
    printcontext.MakeCurrent(nullWindow);
    // GL.Begin(...)
    // ...
    // GL.End()
    // printcontext.SwapBuffers()? Should be single-buffered?
}

void Document_EndPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{

}

void Document_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{

}
```

I also noted the `OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsContext (ContextHandle handle, IWindowInfo window)` constructor but I am not sure what to put for IWindowInfo.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I've just considered is to take a Bitmap snapshot of the rendered image, like here http://www.opentk.com/doc/graphics/save-opengl-rendering-to-disk

Comment: The problem is that it does not scale automatically with different document sizes.